Question on a hydrodynamic double layer potential in Ladyzhenskaya's book
In O.A. Ladyzhenskaya's "mathematical theory of viscous incompressible flow" there appears the following integral potential
$$
W_i(x)=\int_{S} K_{ij}(x,\eta)\phi_j(x)dS_\eta, K_{ij}(x,\eta)=-\frac{3}{4\pi} \frac{(x_i-\eta_i)(x_j-\eta_j)(x_k-\eta_k)}{|x-\eta|^5 }n_k 
$$
(sum over repeated indices)
where $S=\partial \Omega$ is a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ of class $C^{1,\alpha}$ and $n$ is its normal. Also $\phi:S\to \mathbb R^3$ is continuous on $S$.
The author claims that in this case one can prove a uniform bound
$$
\int_S |K_{ij}(x,\eta)|dS_\eta \leq C
$$
for all $x\in \mathbb R^3$.
But does this not imply, by dominated convergence, that  $W_i$ is continuous at least for bounded $\phi$? Then we would get contradiction, as for $\phi=$constant this $W$ is discontinuous as shown in the book.
